# Can we read Quran pak from our phone when on menses?

Tags: quran, salat, quran-recitation, surah, grave

I have read that we are NOT allowed to read the Quran when on menses but I have a question. I know that surah Mulk protects you from the punishment of the grave if u recite it every night and I do read it every night before I sleep other than when I’m on my menses. So even if I don’t read it while on menses if it’s not allowed will I still be saved from the punishment of the grave? Also are we actually not allowed to recite the Quran pak even from our phones while on menses?

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,
You are able to listen to Quran while on your menses. I believe that as long as you are not physically holding the Quran, you should be fine. :)
Do dhikr and dua as much as you can while on your menses.
Hope that helps.
Best,
MIchelle